# Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked after upgrade linux mint kernel

Tags: root, upgrade, software-updates, lock

According to pervious question:

[Halt in Linux mint logo after update and upgrade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/549451/379670)

After changing the GRUB file to:

> linux /boot/.... ro quiet text

When I suspend the OS, I am going to loging page:

[image]
 and after inserting my password this massage comes:

[image]

> ... nouveau... FIFO: SCHED_ERROR 20...

Also by advance option mode in boot mode, it said:

[image]

> Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.

So what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating fstab.  (Fortunately, I keep a copy of the original /etc/fstab after completing a successful upgrade/installation.)

My solution:  Boot with an installation DVD/USB in order to troubleshoot.  Open a terminal.  Mount the drive on which Linux was installed.  Compare /etc/fstab entries with the UUID's from "sudo blkid".  There will be an error in fstab, or there is an error in another fstab entry.

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stack Exchange! Before you answer the question, try to guide the asker through some of the steps you were describing. That way you can verify that their problem is the same as yours. As it stands, it doesn't appear to be an issue with the asker's fstab file.