# boot problem with kali linux 2022.2

Tags: boot, kali-linux

My laptop: lenovo ideapad 310 15ISK
usb : usb 3.0 sandisk 32GB
Kali linux 2022.2

I created usb bootable with this instruction:
[url][https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/live-usb-install-with-linux/[/url]](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/live-usb-install-with-linux/%5B/url%5D)

An after this I added persistence:
[url][https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence/[/url]](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence/%5B/url%5D)

When I try boot I have got:

`[  921.789621] nouveau 0000:03:00.0; fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []`

Or sometimes I have got symbol underscore in left high corner and nothing else.

Or sometimes I have:

`[ 211.741160] mt76x2u 1-3:1.0: vendor request req:07 off:175c failed:-110`

Comment: Very related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549544/cannot-open-access-to-console-the-root-account-is-locked-after-upgrade-linux-mi

Comment: I have not found a solution to the problem using this link

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.